# Importing SPM package in Objc file

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager

I recently integrated SPM into my project and I am trying to import it an Objc .h file.

But Keep getting error of `'SideMenu/SideMenu-Swift.h' file not found`

This is how I am importing it `#import <SideMenu/SideMenu-Swift.h>`

is there any other way to do this please?

Comment: May be just `#import <SideMenu/SideMenu.h>` or `@import SideMenu;`

Comment: if this header you try to import is autogenerated from swift to expose some functions to objc than you should place the `#import` rule in `.m` file and compile once to kick-off the autogeneration process. This is because you don't want cycling references by reestablishing already declared stuff into objc and then back to swift again. If your objc class needs declarations from swift in its interface than use forward declarations in that interface `@class ...;`